# How to deal with multiple error columns in data flow

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I'm writing a simple package to load data into tables and a I have multiple destinations within the same package. I'm attempting to first attempt batch inserts but want to fall back to row by row in case an error is encountered. When the error is encountered in the row by row insert, I'd like to kick that out to an error table. My architecture looks like this:

[image: Sample SSIS setup]

However, I get an error in my Union component because there are multiple ErrorCode and ErrorColumns coming from each flow, one from the batch insert and one from the row by row insert.

[image]

I'm attempting to union the error output together in order to not have to duplicate any logic I want to do with my error handling.

What's the best solution for dealing with this? Is there a way to remove columns from a data flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out shortly after posting.

Although SSIS doesn't allow you to delete the error columns in the error output of the first insert, it does allow you to change the names. I was able to modify the names of these columns and then the Union does not throw any errors as the names are not in conflict anymore.